# Sql statement WHERE clause creation datetime is > than modifiation datetime Print Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this select statement that I'm modifying to print results only if modification time is greater than creation time by 30 min or more.
This how the date and time look -  2015-06-21 1:00:11 .

**Here's the entire select statement:**

```
 $sql = "SELECT `myver`.`id`, `myver`.`name`, `users`.`fn`, `users`.`ln`, `books`.`document_id`, `books`.`creation_datetime`, `books`.`modification_datetime` FROM `" . $db . "`.`myver`, `" . $db . "`.`users`, `" . $db . "`.`books` WHERE `users`.`sserv_id` = `myver`.`id` AND  `books`.`sserv_id` =  `myver`.`id` AND  `users`.`user_uri` = `books`.`primary_user`  AND `books`.`creation_date` = '" . $date . "' AND `books`.`modification_datetime` >= DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) ORDER BY `myver`.`id`, `users`.`fn`,`users`.`ln`, `books`.`document_id`, `books`.`creation_datetime`, `books`.`modification_datetime`";
```

**What was Added:**

```
AND `books`.`creation_datetime` < `books`.`modification_datetime` >= DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

**My Question:**

This gives me 0 results. Not sure how to actually write it.

Here's what I'm trying to say:

If creation_datetime is less than modification_datetime print ALL results if the modification_datetime is greater by 30 minutes or MORE.

Can someone show how I can do this with the SELECT statement provided?

Comment: why do you have 2 intervals ??

Comment: actually it was this that was confusing me: `DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer.

```
AND `books`.`creation_datetime` < DATE_SUB(modification_datetime, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

And Dagon is a dumb ass.